# Looking for a [common] idiom that loosely translates to "I fart you away"

Tags: idioms

A few years ago when I first started learning Mandarin, a friend told me of a certain idiom that's used when you want someone to just leave you alone / go away. I can't recall the idiom in Mandarin but in English it loosely translates to, "I fart you away."

Can someone please provide this idiom and if that's the proper context to use it?

Comment: Are you looking for a rude word? Or a kind one?

Comment: @dan Maybe in between? I think you would be comfortable saying it to a friend and they wouldn't be offended, but probably wouldn't say it to a complete stranger.

Comment: 别在我跟前逼逼 means 走开. but i don't think it's idiom. Any word you remember?

Comment: Obligatory Monty Python quote: [*I fart In your general direction!*](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=I%20Fart%20In%20your%20general%20direction%21).

Answer (score 1):

I guess it is "滚开". That's a insulting idiom.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

"Get lost" is "滚开" or "滚蛋" but it is not an idiom, just a slang

If you want an idiom that contains "fart" and meaning of "go away",  “屁滾尿流”  is the only possible one.

“屁滾尿流” means “farting and pissing uncontrollably  (mostly while running away)” It is a metaphor for  “in extreme fear”

Example::

殺得敵人屁滾尿流地逃走 (beating the enemy so  bad that they wet  themselves while running away)

Comment: OP is looking for "a certain idiom that's used when you want someone to just leave you alone". 屁滾尿流 has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess from your description,

`当我是个屁,把我放了`

Comment: 'I' fart 'you', not 'you' fart 'me'. Hehe :)

Comment: All right, so is it about ```屁```, and how many characters there (is it 4, or more). @dan

Comment: I don't know. I'm not the one who asked the question. :)

Comment: aha, wrong at, sorry then.